# FFMPEG - Concat Image to a video without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been googling this but didn't found a definitive answer.

I need to concat two images to the beginning and end of a video without re-encoding the whole video.

Edit: Please assume i'm using h264 codec with python. Say i need the image to be displayed for 03 seconds.

Can this really be done? If so appreciate a sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is likely codec-dependent, but I suppose if you encode both images as I-frames you can append them to the beginning and possibly the end. However, your question is really broad. The amount of code needed to do this is non-trivial. As such, I think your question is too broad. Also, you've not indicated which language you're using, though I'm assuming C.

Comment: what if i use h264 codec with Python. Say i need the image to be displayed for 03 seconds

Comment: If you encode the images as video streams with the same properties as the main video, it may be possible. Are you using the FFmpeg API or calling the binary.